# How can I select xml:id attributes in an XML file?

Tags: javascript, xml

I am working on an XML file following the MEI standard, which is used for musical notation. The file is very long, for that reason it is accessible [here](http://pastebin.com/3S8DXFbq).

I am trying to select xml:id attributes from TypeScript with:

`myDoc.querySelector('[xml\:id="toto"]');`

`myDoc` has type `Document`.

My problem is that Safari responds `Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12`.
From my basic knowledge, it indicates that the query is malformed.
So I tried to escape `:` char with one more `\`. It makes the exception disappear, but querySelector then responds `null`, indicating it could not found the element.

Any idea how to select a specific **xml:id**?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use selector `[*|id='toto']` to match element with attribute `id` having value `toto`, e.g.,

```
myDoc.querySelector("[*|id='toto']")
```

[Selectors Level 3 6.3.3. Attribute selectors and namespaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attrnmsp)

> CSS examples:
>
> ```
> @namespace foo "http://www.example.com";
> [foo|att=val] { color: blue }
> [*|att] { color: yellow }
> [|att] { color: green }
> [att] { color: green }
> ```
>
> The first rule will match only elements with the attribute att in the
>   "http://www.example.com" namespace with the value "val".
>
> The second rule will match only elements with the attribute att
>   regardless of the namespace of the attribute (including no namespace).
>
> The last two rules are equivalent and will match only elements with
>   the attribute att where the attribute is not in a namespace.

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/frL23SK7DWe6lOroDSVc?p=preview